# Is it correct this definition of determinant?

Tags: determinant

Kay, in the beginning of  book about tensor calculus, explain Laplace expansion of a determinant. I suppose that (because he doesn't define the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix), he still refers to the definition that use permutation symbol, and so Kay manage Laplace expansion not as a definition, but as a tool to make calculations. Well, let's suppose you want to define determinant using Laplace expansion, should you start by defining apart the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix? I thought to something like that:

1. Given a $2 \times 2$ matrix
   \begin{equation}
    \mathsf{M} = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a & b \\ c & d
   \end{bmatrix} 
   \end{equation}I define the determinant as the scalar $ad-bc$.
2. Given an arbitrary square matrix, I define $ij$-minor of a matrix as the scalar $m_{ij}$ given by the determinant of the matrix with row $i$ and column $j$ removed; and $ij$-cofactor as the scalar
   \begin{equation}
    c_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j} m_{ij}
   \end{equation}
3. Finally I define the determinant $\det(\mathsf{A})$ of a matrix $\mathsf{A}$ as the sum of terms of a row, each multiplied by its cofactor, or as the sum of terms of a column, each multiplied by its cofactor.

At first glance this look illogical and circular, because I use determinant to define cofactor, and I use cofactor to define determinant, but it is? I wonder if this is really a problem: I defined the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix so I can find cofactors of a $3 \times 3$ matrix, so I can find determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix, so I can find cofactors of a $4 \times 4$ matrix, and so on. In principle I defined determinant of an arbitrary (squared) matrix. Maybe it's not so practical, but isn't it a valid definition? And if it is the case, how can I do the final step showing that if $a_{ij}$ and $c_{ij}$ are the term $ij$ and the cofactor $ij$ of the square matrix $\mathsf{A}$, then all this sums have the same value?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{1i} c_{1i} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{2i} c_{2i} = \dots = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{in} c_{in} = 
 \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i1} c_{i1} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i2} c_{i2} = \dots = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ni} c_{ni} 
\end{equation}
If there is a simple way to see that, the definition would work?

Comment: The way I learnt this is to show that the space of alternate $n$-multi linear forms on a space of dimension $n$ has dimension $1$, so all of these forms are scalar multiples of each other.
So they are determined by its value on the identity.

Comment: That is shown as Theorem 2 of Chapter 5 of Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze for example.

Comment: The definition is inductive/recursive.  No problems.

Comment: If only there was an easy way to prove that the last equation holds for an n-1xn-1 matrix then it would hold for an nxn matrix, the job would be done. But I fear it is difficult. For now I leave it alone.